# Как вернуть изображение в запросе Axios от сервера во Vuejs?

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

Вопрос в заголовке. А чем вы пользуетесь, чтобы вернуть картинку на клиент загруженную на сервер?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, вы хотите отобразить загружаемую картинку на сервер?

Comment: Не только, но и те которые были загружены ранее.

Comment: Для отображения загружаемых изображений можно воспользоваться [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Для того, чтобы отобразить уже загруженные изображения, вы можете получить ссылки на них и вставить в тег `img` в атрибут `src`.

Comment: Благодарю, я тоже об этом думал.